# What to do when someone's attacking you, but succeeding the save is worse than failing it?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

I was reading through the Monk rules in D&D 5e when I came across this section in the rules for *Quivering Palm*:

> When you use this action, the creature must make a Constitution saving throw. If it fails, it is reduced to 0 hit points. If it succeeds, it takes 10d10 necrotic damage.
>   *PHB pp.80*

The standard expectation of how saving throws work is that if someone's attacking you, *failing* your saving throw brings *worse* results than succeeding, so you naturally want to succeed, and your attacker benefits if you fail.

However, that isn't always the case. Quivering Palm is an example which violates that standard expectation. Suppose you're on very low HP, or you're a very low-constitution wizard with less than 100 max HP to begin with, or you may want to avoid having to make death saving throws, or worse yet, a combination of these things! At that point, *failing* the save and dropping to 0 HP may be a *far* more appealing than succeeding, taking 10d10 necrotic damage, and risking dying outright.

How do you handle this situation that seems counter-intuitive to the rules? Can the rules be reinterpreted so that the best option you're left with is not simply to fail your saving throw? Something that, like normal, gives an advantage to success over failure? Especially since, as [daze413 mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65310/what-to-do-when-someones-attacking-you-but-succeeding-the-save-is-worse-than-f#comment141706_65312) in comments to an answer here, the character doesn't know he should fail.

Comment: I think there's some case for this being a distinct question. In my opinion the talk about voluntarily failing the save is a distraction here, because the problem expressed is actually that the ability is broken in terms of how it is clearly intended to behave. The save effect is supposed to have a lower magnitude than the non-save effect, but since they operate on completely different mathematical principles, that is not the case.

Comment: @trekkieyk I've done some editing to try and better express some parts of this issue. Please check it over and see if you're OK with it, and edit further if you'd like.

Comment: Please quit with the comments.  Answer the question if desired. Though it still looks like a duplicate to me. Closing as duplicate, unless it is edited to be distinct.

Comment: Definitely a unique question now.

Comment: This question, if it is confined only to the high level monk skill, stands on its own.  If it were to be rephrased to just address the monk skill, rather than saves in general, it should be re-opened.  Some of the points in the other thread about what a saving throw represents may be raised, but with a specific save and skill effect to focus on.  (Aside: 10d10 is 55 hp average).

Comment: This definitely doesn't look like a duplicate to me...

Answer (score 8):

DMG p. 237

> Remember that dice don't run your
> game- you do. Dice are like rules. They're
> tools to help keep the action moving. At any
> time, you can decide that a player's action is
> automatically successful.

and DMG p. 242

> **RESOLUTION AND CONSEQUENCES**
>
> **You determine the consequences** of attack rolls, ability
> checks, and saving throws. In most cases, doing so is
> straightforward. When an attack hits, it deals damage.
> When a creature fails a saving throw, the creature
> suffers a harmful effect.

when read in conjunction with **How to Play** (PHB p. 6):

1. The DM describes the environment.
2. The players describe what they want to do.
3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’
   actions.

gives the following outcome:

1. "The monk strikes you with Quivering Palm - there's a DCX Constitution save, if you fail you are at 0hp, if you succeed you take 10d10 damage."
2. "Ugh! I only have a hp max of 30 and I'm at 10hp right now; if I succeed an average roll could kill me outright! Can I automatically fail my save?"
3. "Hmm ... OK, you automatically fail; you are at 0 hp."

Easy.

### Edit

There have been comments to the effect that allowing the *player* to decide that the *character* automatically fails is a meta-game tactic. Apart from begging the question ([Can we affirm that RPG.SE embraces a plurality of playstyles?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/can-we-affirm-that-rpg-se-embraces-a-plurality-of-playstyles)) that meta-gaming is, of itself, wrong in some way; a meta-game solution is the *only* one applicable here.

In-fiction a *character* has been struck by an effect (Quivering Palm) which will render him unconscious if he is **unlucky** or kill him if he is **lucky**. In what fiction does this make sense? The fiction is broken; it needs an out-of-fiction solution.

We are talking about hit points and saving throws - these are meta-game constructs. The *characters* have no in-fiction knowledge of such things or their mechanical resolution; they only make sense to the players and the DM so only the players and the DM can make decisions about them.

Comment: I invite you to elaborate on the context and significance of this quote and connect the dots between that quote and "players can fail a saving throw if they want." A single brief quote intended for a very different context and participant (the DM), from a book the player might not even have, with a snappy "No worries" does not provide much clarity or enlightenment for newbies.

Comment: How would the *character* know the of choice anyway? Did he have extensive experience dealing with high level monks? Does he think: "ok if I don't resist, this'll go alot smoother for me"?

Comment: @daze413 What does the character have to do with it? **How to Play** is about the players and the DM. The player knows because the DM told her; the character fails the save because the player described that and the DM agreed.

Comment: @DaleM Yes, but it sounds like metagaming to me.

Comment: @daze413 Among many tables, metagaming is not seen as a bad thing, and in fact may be standard fare for play. [We embrace that fact](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5174/1204). Something seeming like metagaming is therefore not itself a problem.

Comment: In the potential duplicate answer, the target goes along on purpose because the spell is beneficial, and more to the point, he knows what's going on and what the spell is going to do. Here, as daze413 said, there's no such expectation. @doppelgreener, granted that some people are open to explicit metagaming, but not everyone is. I think that an answer that fits both camps has the potential to be stronger than one that doesn't.